# How to attach multiple .dmg files present in a folder using python in macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

Multiple .dmg files are present in a particular folder,Using python how could i mount those .dmg files iteratively.
I tried the following code

```
    import os
    path = '/Users/kat/Desktop/pro'
    os.chdir(path)
    for i in os.scandir(path):
     print(i)
     os.system("hdiutil attach i")
```

But i get "hdiutil" command not found error.Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something more like this:

```
import os, glob

os.chdir('/Users/kat/Desktop/pro')

for i in glob.glob("*.dmg"): 
    print(i) 
    os.system(f'hdiutil attach "{i}"')
```

Python *"f-strings"* are described [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code. The command is actually `hdiutil`.

Comment: Hello yeah i corrected the command but still I get the same error